# Display as percentages using openxlsx::addStyle without having to click on cell in Excel

Tags: r, openxlsx

Currently, I've used openxlsx::addStyle to add percentages to certain rows and columns

```
pct <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt="PERCENTAGE")
  
openxlsx::addStyle(wkbk, sheet = this_sheet, style=pct, cols=2:4, rows=7:9), gridExpand=TRUE)

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wkbk,file = file_out,overwrite = TRUE)
```

When I save the workbook, the data is of the correct data type in Excel. However, it doesn't format with the percentage sign - I have to click on it to get it to change.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior so it will format properly by default?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it seems to work for me. I don't have your data so I have included a reproducible example that shows it working.

```
library(openxlsx)
wkbk <- createWorkbook('workbook')
addWorksheet(wkbk, 'Sheet')
pct <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt="PERCENTAGE")
writeData(wkbk, sheet=1, USPersonalExpenditure)
openxlsx::addStyle(wkbk, sheet = 1, style = pct, cols=1:6, rows=2:6, gridExpand=TRUE)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wkbk, file = 'wkbk.xlsx', overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you per chance know what your Excel's default setting is? I was reading somewhere about the difference between Excel opening in "edit mode" versus "read mode" that might be a contributing factor. And if so, do you know how to programmatically set this mode?

Comment: Nope, same issue as before. When I open the Excel, it shows that the values are in number format "Percentage". However, they look like regular numbers until I double-click on them.

Comment: I opened my xlsx file using LibreOffice Calc and it displayed OK using that. I also uploaded my file to Google Drive and used Google Sheets to successfully display it. I'm afraid my knowledge of Excel settings is not enough to know if this is the root cause of your problem and what to do about it.